# Nodejs Generate a keys to sign a piece of data

Tags: node.js, cryptography, digital-signature

I have some blob data for example:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from('ACDFF12BA','hex');
```

How I can generate keys in order to sign it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is by using the `keypair` npm package:

```
const keypair = require('keypair');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const pair = keypair();

// Create Transmitted Signature
const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update('abcdef');  // data from your file would go here
const sig = sign.sign(pair.private, 'hex');
console.log(sig);

// Verifying Signature
const verify = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verify.write('abcdef');
verify.end();
console.log(verify.verify(pair.public, sig,'hex'));
```

As you can see using the `keypair()` function I generate the public and the private keys via a `sign.sign` I generate the signature. Keep in mind to sign with a Private Key. The generated the public key in the following format:

```
--- RSA BEGIN PUBLIC KEY ---
^some base64 here^
--- RSA END PUBLIC KEY ---
```

And the generated private key will have the same format:

```
--- RSA BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ---
^some base64 here^
--- RSA END PRIVATE KEY ---
```

Now the only thing to do is to stringify the buffer as a hex string and do the job. Keep in mind that the receiving end needs to verify the data as hex string as well.

We can verify the signature with the `verify.verify` and a public key. Keep in mind on the signature's format as well. In case you generate a hex encoded signature then verify it in the same format.

Also the methodology above is recommended when the native `crypto.generateKeyPair` is not available (eg. in electron applications)

Comment: Generating the key pair is commonly not the big issue; creating trust in the public key is, which is why commonly a [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) needs to be set up. Stringifying is only required if you cannot handle binary data; it is performed *way* too often in my opinion.

Comment: Well I had the issue using the native `generateKeyPair` over electron application thus it is somewhat usefull to keep track on solutions in my problems.

Comment: I presume every library that contains RSA functionality has functionality to generate a key pair - usually with the sample code to go with it. I was therefore very much thinking about closing it as too broad or as asking for examples, to be honest. Problem is too that there is little in the form of peer review; just creating code snippets to allow for easy copying is very dangerous. I've had to issue warnings for many code snippets.

Comment: What does `pair.private` generate in the log? Which signature algorithm is being used to generate the signature? What is the encoding performed on the input string during `update`?

Comment: An RSA Encoded Key like the ones used un the ssh starting with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` then follows the key encoded as base64  and then closes as `---END RSA PRIVATE KEY---` of course this key it to be stored locally and never come out.

Comment: I would suggest it should also not be logged. Log the key fingerprint if you have to, but not an unprotected private key.That's an OpenSSL PEM encoded RSA private key which consists of the PKCS#1 DER encoding. SSH may just *use* that key format.

Comment: Yell yes it is for only debugging purpoces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186546/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-dimitrios-desyllas).